# loop with mysql update - only the first works

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have a small loop that updates a few records in one table
only the first update seems to work
but the others don't cause errors
do I need to do something to allow the subsequent updates?

```
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $values = $fieldData[$i];
    $sql = "UPDATE " .$tableName. " " .$alias. " SET " .$values. " WHERE UPPER(CONCAT_WS('" .$fieldConcatenate. "'," .$keyFields. "))=UPPER('" .$keyData[$i]. "')";
    try {
        echo "sql: " .$sql. "\n";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        echo "ok\n";
        $sql = '';
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "update failed: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Like a sample array with data. We could assume that your $count variable is equal to 1 ands so only one iteration is executed

Comment: $count = 1 always works, $count = 2, both update statements are executed, but only the first has any effect on the database. the values are not important as each update works by itself :)

Comment: then your second statement just updating the same data

Comment: in fact the fieldData array provides different values. i added some extra debug statements. turns out the idiot who prepared fieldData managed to slip an extra comma into the data for 2nd and subsequent rows :embarrassed: thanks for listening, I'll crawl back into my cave now